# How to quickly check if NSString object is a valid url?

Tags: iphone, nsstring

Help me to write the code like "if my string is a valid URL do smth"
Is it possible to write this in a couple strings of code?

Comment: By "valid" do you simply mean meeting syntax requirements, or do you mean pointing to an existing site?

Comment: I need just the right syntax..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I will assume that by URL, you are referring to a string identifying a internet resource location.

If you have an idea about the format of the input string , then why not manually check if the string starts with `http://`, `https://` or any other scheme you need. If you expect other protocols, you can also add them to the check list (e.g. `ftp://`, `mailto://`, etc)

```
if ([myString hasPrefix:@"http://"] || [myString hasPrefix:@"https://"])
{
    // do something
}
```

If you are looking for a more solid solution and detect any kind of URL scheme, then you should use a regular expression.

As a side note, the NSURL class is designed to express any kind of resource location (not just internet resources). That is why, strings like `img/demo.jpg` or `file://bla/bla/bla/demo.jpg` can be transformed into NSURL objects.

However, according to the documentation the `[NSURL URLWithString]` should return nil if the input string is not a valid internet resource string. In practice it doesn't.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks. And the most important that it works fine for me.

Answer (score 7):

```
+ (BOOL)validateUrlString:(NSString*)urlString
{
    if (!urlString)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    NSDataDetector *linkDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];

    NSRange urlStringRange = NSMakeRange(0, [urlString length]);
    NSMatchingOptions matchingOptions = 0;

    if (1 != [linkDetector numberOfMatchesInString:urlString options:matchingOptions range:urlStringRange])
    {
        return NO;
    }

    NSTextCheckingResult *checkingResult = [linkDetector firstMatchInString:urlString options:matchingOptions range:urlStringRange];

    return checkingResult.resultType == NSTextCheckingTypeLink 
        && NSEqualRanges(checkingResult.range, urlStringRange);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I used this solution which is apparently a better and less complex check than a Regex check -

```
- (BOOL)isURL:(NSString *)inputString
{
    NSURL *candidateURL = [NSURL URLWithString:inputString];
    return candidateURL && candidateURL.scheme && candidateURL.host;
}
```

Comment: That method will accept things like `""` or `"img/demo.jpg"` as @andrei-stanescu pointed out, and it's probably not what the OP had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create NSUrl with it, and see if it returns non-nil result.

Comment: I've already tried that:
    if ([NSURL urlWithString:urlString] != nil){
    
    }
but for some reason it just returns me my string!!
(Though the method description say that it must return nil if string is not a valid url..don't really know why)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([NSURL URLWithString:text]) {
  // valid URL
}
else {
  // invalid URL
}
```

Comment: that's the point it doesn't work...have I met a strange bug or what???
I have a log in the if NSLog(@"invalid url:%@", [NSURL URLWithString:urlString]); And it shows me:
invalid url:img/playgrounds.png

Comment: This is why you should say what you've already tried in your question. If your string is literally "img/playgrounds.png" then it is correct; that's not a valid URL. If you try it with, say, `http://img.ly/playground.png` then it will work.