# See if a NSString is an website URL in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

How to find out if a `NSString` is an website URL in `Objective-c`.It will be better if you provide source code. If not, tell me which class is useful is good enough.

Finally i found a way to judge,may not the best way,but useful :

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
    NSURL *lazyUrlStr = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@",urlStr]];
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]){
            NSLog(@"it's a url");
    }else if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:lazyUrlStr]){
        NSLog(@"it's a url");
    }else{NSLog(@"it isn't a url");
```

}

FYI: urlStr is the NSString to be judged

Comment: @JJ.Yuan: I think it may not be a `UIString`, it'll be `NSString`. Because `UI` always refers to `UserInterface` components.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objective-C - Checking if URL exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008399/objective-c-checking-if-url-exists)

Comment: i don't think so Patrick

Comment: duplicated question [How to quickly check if NSString object is a valid url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260779/how-to-quickly-check-if-nsstring-object-is-a-valid-url)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8224568/653513

Comment: i know i know.. but i don't want to Yuan to hate this site. He is just a beginner. Let him study

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate an url on the iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471201/how-to-validate-an-url-on-the-iphone)

Comment: @Jeff It's not a duplicate of that question as the OP wants to know if the string is a URL to a website (i.e. http/https), not just a valid URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `URLWithString` method of `NSURL` (if you are asking for `NSString`, not `UIString`):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:yourUrlString];
if (url && url.scheme && url.host)
{
   //the url is ok
   NSLog(@"URL:%@", yourUrlString);
}
```

Hope this will help:)

Comment: Also test the value of `scheme`?

Comment: i use below ,is it better ?

if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]){
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}

Comment: @RonakChaniyara It is required, as your answer will be valid for a file url, which is not a reference to a website.